# "An administrator password must be specified" error on Azure Create Virtual Machine REST API

Tags: windows, rest, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a new Windows VM using Windows Azure REST API.
But, I keep getting the following error:

```
BadRequest: An administrator password must be specified
```

But, the REST call XML body does include:

```
<AdminPassword>SomePassword123</AdminPassword>
<AdminUsername>guyk</AdminUsername>
```

Any clue where should I start looking?

Comment: One thing I would recommend is that you check the order of XML elements. Service Management API is very peculiar about it.

Comment: @GauravMantri how can I find the right order? There is no official xml schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by a missing "type" attribute in the ConfigurationSet

```
            <ConfigurationSet xsi:type="WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet">
```